# What is the proper way to setup Rados Gateway (RGW) under Ceph using Cephadm?

Tags: haproxy, ceph, ceph-rgw

I have setup a 'reef' Ceph Cluster using Cephadm and Ansible in a lab environment. I have buckets and pools already setup. The ceph.io site is confusing on how to setup the Rados Gateway (radosgw) with Multi-site -- https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multisite/

Is a copy of HAProxy also needed for handling the front-end load balancing or is it implied that Ceph sets it up?

Command-line scripting I was planning on using for setting up the RGW:

```
radosgw-admin realm create --rgw-realm=sandbox --default
radosgw-admin zonegroup create --rgw-zonegroup=sandbox  --master --default
radosgw-admin zone create --rgw-zonegroup=sandbox --rgw-zone=sandbox --master --default
radosgw-admin period update --rgw-realm=sandbox --commit
ceph orch apply rgw sandbox --realm=sandbox --zone=sandbox --placement="2 ceph-mon1 ceph-mon2" --port=8000
```

What other steps are needed to get the RGW up and running so that it can be presented to something like Veeam for doing performance and I/O testing concepts?

-- Michael

Comment: If you need high availability you need to create an additional [ingress service](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/services/rgw/#high-availability-service-for-rgw), for example via spec file. Then cephadm will deploy haproxy instances as well. Do you have data pools created for RGW? I'm not entirely sure, but I believe you need to create the buckets.data and buckets.index pools manually because their configuration (replicated or EC, devices classes etc.) is up to the admin's requirements. You might need to add endpoints to the zones/zonegroups pointing to the RGW (or the loadbalancer).